# How many domains can be associated with an EC2 instance simultaneously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, multiple-instances

How many domains can be associated simultaneously with an EC2 instance which runs on windows 2012 Server with SQL Web ?

We have 5*n domain names to host on these servers, n stands for number of versions we run parallel to each other..

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear but with just one ElasticIP you can host nearly infinite domain names to that IP. Then use Apache Virtuahosts, or IIS equivalent, to serve the websites. Just point the needed DNS records to the ElasticIP associated to the EC2 instance.

There are many possible limitations to this, like storage, memory, SSL certificates on the same IP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No limit, as long as your server doesn't fall over.